# Can't compile Format.h 'fmt::v8::detail::do_throw' not found? c++14

Tags: c++, compilation, include, game-engine, spdlog

The code was compiling fine until the compiler shown that error. It's the second time that it happened to me, I didn't solved yet, I just copied a last version of my project when it happened for the first time. On both, it just appeared doing nothing, just adding some new class on the project... Also I tried to download again the spdlog library, but it didn't worked. It seems that I overdeclared some macro or function? but I rlly didn't, i'm so confused about it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MF38.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.